# How to output 2D array from two 1D arrays?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two arrays I need to output a 2D array from:

```
let id = productArrays.map { $0.productID }=["2", "2"]
let quant = productArrays.map { $0.quantity }=["3", "4"]
var array = [[Int]]()
        for i in 0..<productArrays.count {
            var subArray = quant
            for j in 0..<productArrays.count {
                subArray[i]![j] = quant
            }
            array.append(subArray)
        }
}
```

I need to output like this:

```
[[3, 2],[4, 2]]
```

Comment: post the nature of the issue you are facing

Comment: Could you show us what `productArrays` contains originally, some kind of struct or?

Comment: post the original two arrays please

Comment: The orgenal array id = ["2", "2"] and quant = ["3", "4"]

Comment: I need to do 2D array like this [["2","3"],["2","4"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let id = ["2", "2"]
let quant = ["3", "4"]
let result = Array(zip(id, quant))
```

Comment: This creates an array with two tuples

Answer (score 0):

Update, a solution for using `zip`

```
let array = zip(id, quant).map {[$0.0, $0.1]}
```

or if you prefer the array to contain integers

```
let array = zip(id, quant).map {[Int($0.0) ?? 0, Int($0.1) ?? 0]}
```

---

Here is a simple solution to merge and convert the array elements

```
let id = ["2", "2"]
let quant = ["3", "4"]

var array = [[Int]]()

let end = min(id.count, quant.count)
for i in 0..<end {
    if let id = Int(id[i]), let quant = Int(quant[i]) {
        array.append([id, quant])
    }
}
```

---

Since the question contains a `map` on an array I wanted to include an alternative solution in case that the original data is contained in some struct (in an array) since such a solution is pretty straightforward

```
struct Item { //My made up struct
    let id: String
    let quant: String
}

let productArray = [Item(id: "2", quant: "3"), Item(id: "2", quant: "4")]

let array2 = productArray.compactMap { item -> [Int]? in
    if let id = Int(item.id), let quant = Int(item.quant) {
        return [id, quant]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @ShahedAboSaleem I have updated my answer with a correct solution for using `zip` that gets you the desired 2D array.